# Flink Collector Issue While ReadValue from FasterXML

Tags: apache-flink

I have Kafka values as String, and POJO as below,

```
{"name":"John","timeStamp":"2020-08-11T13:31:31"}
```

```
class Person{
    
    private String name;    

    private LocalDateTime timeStamp; 
}
```

this Time Stamp comes as String from Kafka, and converting them into `LocalDateTime`.

When i run the program as Standalone and `objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class)` using required library from FasterXML, it works fine. It's converting.

When I read from Flink Framework with the below,

```
 stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Person>() {
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Person> out) {
                try {
                    out.collect(objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).print();
        env.execute();
```

I'm getting the below issue,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper@1b7cc17c is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
```

The message shows me the Person object is not serializable, and i have implemented `Serializable` for `Person` class  but no luck. And also, tried below, not luck too.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
```

**UPDATE:**

Looks like issue with API, i read in the below link,

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception states that the `JsonMapper` instance is not `Serializable` - if I'm not mistaken, it has been made serializable as of version `2.1`. Also, `Person` class should be made serializable as well.

So, in your case I would say you should either switch to `jackson-databind` version `>=2.1` or probably make JsonMapper `static` field.

In case of `Person` class, just simply implement `Serializable` interface:

```java
class Person implements Serializable {
    
    private String name;    

    private LocalDateTime timeStamp; 
}
```

Comment: I tried with implementing ```Serializable``` but no luck as mentioned already.

Comment: @user2182920, the initial exception provided by you states that `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper@1b7cc17c` is not serializable. Have you tried to make mapper static ? Also, could you please provide the `jackson-databind` library version you are using ? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used ```jackson-databind``` version ```2.11.0``` and tried with 2 approaches, 1. Making Person class is serializable, 2. static Person class with/out serializable.  Both are gives me same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I probably was not clear enough. I meant, you need to make local variable `objectMapper` static. I would say that the issue is `JsonMapper` serialibility, so what I would suggest is to try either
(1) make local variable `objectMapper` static
(2) or if (1) does not help just to ensure this is not a problem - try to replace `out.collect(objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class));` with `out.collect(new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, Person.class));` - I know this is not the way it should be done, but at least for testing purpose.